# if else with number comparison in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have this code :

```
#!/bin/env bash
output=$(echo -e 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211 | awk 'NR==2');
echo "$output"

typeset -i output=0

if [ $output -eq 0 ];

then
   echo "User exists"
else
   echo "User doesn't exists"
 fi
```

in the above code the actual output of the line `output=$(echo -e 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211 | awk 'NR==2');` without the `awk 'NR==2'` flag is :

```
VALUE mykey 0 1
0
END
```

the code echo "$output" with the `awk 'NR==2'`  prints the value 0 or whatever is there at the second row in the above output.

The code always gives User Exists even when the output is some other number than 0.

Why is the comparison not working here?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: /bin/sh is usually not bash.

Comment: Remove `typeset -i output=0`

Comment: If you are really using `/bin/sh`, you don't need the `-e` option on `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax issues aside, this is what you're doing:

```
output="some value"
output=0
if [ $output -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

Don't reassign the variable after capturing the initial value.